# Want to email file to a google app for others to access

Tags: google, google-drive, google-workspace

Google Docs used to let you email docs to it.  Now they turned that off.  I need that feature to collect match score reports by email and allow all coaches to see all reports.  The coaches are reporting scores in a pdf form that will be emailed.  We have a Google Site running on the free version of Google Apps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Google Groups instead. They still have an email address.